# Rust is unable to borrow inside a for loop

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

In the following source code, `cartesian_system_test_1()` runs okay.  But, `cartesian_system_test_2()` doesn't run because it uses loops.

The two variations are essentially the same code one is not using a loop and the other uses a for loop.

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod cartesian_system_test {
    use bioshell_cartesians::{CartesianSystem, Coordinates, NbList, PolymerRules};
    use bioshell_numerical::Vec3;

    fn do_modify_vector(vec: &mut Vec3)
    {
        vec.x = 0.0;
        vec.y = 0.0;
        vec.z = 0.0;
    }

    #[test]
    fn cartesian_system_test_1() {
        const E_TO: f64 = 6.0;
        let buffer_thickness = 4.0;
        let nbl: NbList = NbList::new(E_TO, buffer_thickness, Box::new(PolymerRules {}));
        let mut coords = Coordinates::new(3);//create a coordinate of length: 5.
        coords.add(0, 1.0,1.0,1.0);
        coords.add(1, 2.0,2.0,2.0);
        coords.add(2, 3.0,3.0,3.0);

        let mut system: CartesianSystem = CartesianSystem::new(coords, nbl);

        let mut system_coords = system.coordinates();

        assert_eq!(system.coordinates()[0], Vec3::new(1.0, 1.0, 1.0));
        assert_eq!(system.coordinates()[1], Vec3::new(2.0, 2.0, 2.0));
        assert_eq!(system.coordinates()[2], Vec3::new(3.0, 3.0, 3.0));

        let mut vec_0 = system_coords[0].clone();
        let mut vec_1 = system_coords[1].clone();
        let mut vec_2 = system_coords[2].clone();

        do_modify_vector(&mut vec_0);
        do_modify_vector(&mut vec_1);
        do_modify_vector(&mut vec_2);

        system.set_vec(0, vec_0);
        system.set_vec(1, vec_1);
        system.set_vec(2, vec_2);

        assert_eq!(system.coordinates()[0], Vec3::new(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
        assert_eq!(system.coordinates()[1], Vec3::new(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
        assert_eq!(system.coordinates()[2], Vec3::new(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    }

    #[test]
    fn cartesian_system_test_2() {
        const E_TO: f64 = 6.0;
        let buffer_thickness = 4.0;
        let nbl: NbList = NbList::new(E_TO, buffer_thickness, Box::new(PolymerRules {}));
        let mut coords = Coordinates::new(3);
        coords.add(0, 1.0,1.0,1.0);
        coords.add(1, 2.0,2.0,2.0);
        coords.add(2, 3.0,3.0,3.0);

        let mut system: CartesianSystem = CartesianSystem::new(coords, nbl);

        let mut system_coords = system.coordinates();

        assert_eq!(system.coordinates()[0], Vec3::new(1.0, 1.0, 1.0));
        assert_eq!(system.coordinates()[1], Vec3::new(2.0, 2.0, 2.0));
        assert_eq!(system.coordinates()[2], Vec3::new(3.0, 3.0, 3.0));

        for i in 0..3{
            let mut vec = system_coords[i].clone();
            do_modify_vector(&mut vec);
            system.set_vec(i, vec);
        }

        assert_eq!(system.coordinates()[0], Vec3::new(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
        assert_eq!(system.coordinates()[1], Vec3::new(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
        assert_eq!(system.coordinates()[2], Vec3::new(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    }
}
```

Can you suggest how to make the code inside the for-loop work?

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `system` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> bioshell-cartesians\tests\test_cartesian_system.rs:69:13
   |
60 |         let mut system_coords = system.coordinates();
   |                                 -------------------- immutable borrow occurs here
...
67 |             let mut vec = system_coords[i].clone();
   |                           ------------- immutable borrow later used here
68 |             do_modify_vector(&mut vec);
69 |             system.set_vec(i, vec);
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it? If you get a compilation error, show it.

Comment: @interjay, plz, chek the error message.

Comment: These are actually *not* the same, since in the loop case different operations interleave, whereas they don't in the not loop version.

Comment: The error message makes it very clear that the declaration of `system_coords` cannot coexist with the mutable borrow after (`system.set_vec`). It does not have to do with having a loop, but with having created a long-lasting immutable borrow in `system_coords`.

Comment: @Enet4, what is the solution then?

Comment: Use `system.coordinates()` instead of `system_coords`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first test you clone all vectors, edit them end then update them. In the second test you clone one vector, edit it and update it. Then you clone the second vector. That's not possible because you can't read from `system_coords` while modifying it (it's only borrowed, the modification of `system` is also a modification of `system_coords`). To solve this you have to clone `system.coordinates()` (`let mut system_coords = system.coordinates().clone();`)